# Sitecore Embedded Form - Form Id is not specified in Sitecore JSS

Tags: jss, sitecore-forms, layout-service

I'm trying to build the Embedded form on the website. So I have created a form on the Sitecore website and Sitecore API Key based on [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-manager/api-keys-for-the-odata-item-service.html)

browse load the HTML website faced the below error

[image]

My HTML code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sitecore Embeddable Forms Sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="my-page-container">
      <h1>Sitecore Embeddable Forms Sample</h1>
      <div class="my-embeddable-form-container">
      <scef-form formId="{9320F8B7-7199-42AE-B653-0281A3451E4E}"></scef-form>
     
      </div>
    </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./sitecore-embeddableforms.umd.js?sc_site=https://sitename&sc_apikey=2A72FB75-5D3C-402F-A6C1-EB34ED5C1140"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the issue here is the src value. Could you try with `src="https://yousitecoresite/sitecore-embeddableforms.umd.js?sc_apikey=APIKey"`  Also I hope you already place `sitecore-embeddableforms.umd.js` file into root folder of Sitecore site.

Comment: I have the same problem right now, did you manage to get it working after?

Answer (score 0):

When I was experimenting with EFF on my local system, I encountered a similar problem. To address this issue, I decided to create a new local host site using IIS. I then placed the HTML file and CSS folder into the root folder of the local host site. By accessing the local host through IIS, I managed to resolve the problem.

Comment: I have followed same steps what you did.